# Symbols used in partitions

Tags: symbols

What is the LaTeX code for the symbols for the set of all odd partition and the set of all distinct partitions? I need to use them for a chapter on Euler's theorem in a report about partition theory.

They are both on page 3 of this article on the last line of theorem 1.1: *Chen, William Y. C.; Yee, Ae Ja; Zhu, Albert J. W.*, [**Euler’s partition theorem with upper bounds on multiplicities**](https://doi.org/10.37236/2318), Electron. J. Comb. 19, No. 3, Research Paper P41, 15 p. (2012).

[image: Screenshot of Theorem 1.1.]

Answer (score 1):

using `$\mathcal{D}$` and `$\mathcal{O}$`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \sum_{\lambda \in \mathcal{D}} y^{l_a(\lambda)}q^{|\lambda|} = \sum_{\mu\in\mathcal{O}}y^{l(\mu)}q^{|\mu|}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But note that the mathcal font in use might be quite different

Comment: I know. You can see on PDF properties that the paper used `Computer modern` font. So, I'm sure that the symbol is typed with `\mathcal`.